# Dynamic Reporting Services

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I am building a application called School Management in which the "Report-Card" of students will be prepared.

I tried out the "Crystal Reporting" option in Visual Studio2010. But I am not getting how to build a report which can accept the ID of student dynamically and prepare its report coz I cannot prepare each report card manually.

Please excuse me if this question is a cake-walk. I am relatively new to this.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a "student id" parameter on the table as a dynamic parameter and then use it as the basis of the "WHERE" clause of your select statement. Should be relatively easy and everything I mentioned is in the help files.

note: i only give people tools to solve their problem never the full solution this is because it is a self-evident truth that I am lazy